# Will this code go well resizing for iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-5

Will this code go well resizing for iPhone 5

```
view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get iPhone 5 simulator 
In Xcode 4.5 :
Goto: iOS Simulator->Hardware-> Devices
and then select iPhone retina 4-inch

Answer (score 0):

In order for the app to use entire screen of iPhone 5 you just have to include launch image for 4" screen in your app. Otherwise it won't occupy the whole screen regardless of autoresizing masks.

Comment: What will work? For your app to support iPhone 5 screen it has to include launch image - it's documented. Will your UI correctly scale for the new screen resolution - I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things that need to happen.

1. As @mifki said, you need to include the default launch image for the
   iPhone 5. This will enable the use of the full height in your app.
2. Setting the autosizing mask will only work if your code is set to
   position its view using the bounds of the view. If your code is
   using hardcoded coordinates simply by setting the autosizing mask
   won't work.